# GWT split points with redundant fragments?

Tags: java, gwt, split, gwt-compiler

I'm using GWT.runAsync to split the cod into different fragments. I have a problem with the leftover fragment (reaching 1.2 Mb) and that's because the widgets that I use are interdependent.

I know that if I use runAsync to load a code for a widget (or a subsystem) in more than one location (for that specific class), the code will end up in the left-over fragments. My problem is that my widgets have a lot of dependencies between them and it is almost impossible to use runAsync (and async provider pattern described in GWT splitting documentation) for each of my main components, in one single location.

So, my question, is it possible to make the GWT compiler create more than 1 leftover fragment ? For example, creating redundant js files, which will sum up to more than 1.2MB, but with smaller sizes (individually).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need this compiler flag:

XfragmentCount=X

Docu here:
http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/fragment_merging.html

Comment: Available at 2.5.1 (RC1) or newer :)
You might want to try -XenableClosureCompiler too for reduced .js filesize.